# Response.Redirect equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, redirect

I'm trying to change from VB.Net to C# and I'm a little stuck. In VB.Net when I choose the details view in the tab on the left and then I choose `ItemUpdated` from the tab on the right then write in `Response.Redirect("customer.aspx")`. I cannot get this to do the same thing in C#. The VB.Net code I had is:

```
Protected Sub customerDetDetailsView_ItemUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles customerDetDetailsView.ItemUpdated
    Response.Redirect("customer.aspx")
End Sub
```

I tried this in C#, but its not working for me

```
protected void customerDetDetailsView_ItemUpdated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("customer.aspx");
}
```

Has anyone any idea what I should be doing for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Try with following in c#:**

```
protected void customerDetDetailsView_ItemUpdated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("customer.aspx",false);
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Bind** the method `customerDetDetailsView_ItemUpdated` to the event `customerDetDetailsView.ItemUpdated`

Add something like this in PageLoad

```
customerDetDetailsView.ItemUpdated +={tab}...
```

Comment: I figured out what was happening. I had to copy the function name customerDetDetails_ItemUpdate into the details view header on the other page and delete the line onpageindexchanging. Dont know why but its working now anyway.